# Put HTML into submit button's value

Tags: html, forms, input, submit

I have a submit button that is used to save a form.  Inside the submit button I want to use a HTML tag.  I am using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) and I would like the save icon to appear next to the word save in the button.  The HTML for this is

```
<i class="icon-save"></i> Save
```

The only problem is I cannot seem to get HTML to render inside the `value=""` property on the submit button.  How can I get HTML to render inside the submit button?  This doesn't parse the HTML, it actually renders a button with the literal contents

```
<input type="submit" value="<i class='icon-save'></i> Save" />
```

[Here is an example of what I want](http://jsfiddle.net/d8sNv/1/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

did you try the  `button` tag like this :

```
<button type="submit">
   <i class='icon-save'></i> Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using background image can also achieve this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssASY/)

```
<input type="button" 
       style="background-image:url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/ravenna-3d/24/Access-icon.png);
       background-position:left; background-repeat:no-repeat; 
       padding-left:30px; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px; padding-right:4px" 
       value="Save" />​
```